# Reasoning about integrable positive function

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

past Thursday I had my Calculus exam on integrals. I found a question of the test really challenging and also very interesting. The problem asked the following:

*Let f be an integrable (Riemann) function in the interval [0,2] whose minimum is f(1)=0. We define $F:[0,2] \leftarrow \mathbb R$ by $F(x) = \int_1^x f(t)dt$. Do the following statements always hold?
(i) $F'(1)=0$, (ii) $F$ is a increasing function, (iii)$F'(x)=f(x)$ except for a finite number of points.*

For (i) I proposed $ |\sin(\frac{1}{x-1})|$ if $x \not = 1$ and $0$ if $x=1$ as a counterexample. However, I'm not sure this function would work, I just tried to find a function continuous in every point of $[0,2]$ except for $x=1$ and that $lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$ didn't exist.

For (ii) I argued it was true as, given $x,y \in [0,2]: x < y$, then note that $f(x)\geq0, \forall x \in [0,2]$, thus $F(y)-F(x) = \int_1^y f- \int_1^x f= \int_x^y f \geq (y-x) \cdot 0 = 0$.

For (iii) I tried to look for a function discontinuous in an infinite number of points but integrable as a counterexample. I inspired in Spivak's problem which proved that $g(x)=0$ if x is irrational, $g(\frac{p}{q}) = \frac{1}{q}$, where $\frac{p}{q}$ is a irreducible fraction, is integrable in $[0,1]$ and its integral is exactly 0. Thus, I thought of defining f as g in $[0,1)$, and $f(x)=0$ for $x\in [1,2]$. I think that F(x) would then be a constant 0 function hence $F'(x) \not = f(x)$ for every rational point in $[0,1)$, which is an infinite number of points.

I did this question in less than 10 minutes as I left it as the last one, so I'm quite sure I'm wrong in some of the answers (specially (i) and (iii)). Thus, I would like some feedback and specially other approaches to the activity. I find quite difficult to find good counterexamples in analysis, so I would also appreciate advice/good references to practice this sort of questions.

Comment: For (i) you can take $f(x)=1$ for $x \neq 1$ and $f(1)=0$.

Comment: True, I thought of defining a function such that $F(x)$ wasn't differentiable in $x=1$, but it's easier to look for a function which forces $F'(1)$ be non-zero.

Comment: A function $f$ is Riemann integrable in an closed bounded interval iff $f$ is continuous everywhere except in a set of measure $0$ (sets of measure zero are defined in many Calculus books (Spivak fir example) as sets that can be covered by a countably many open intervals whose lengths add something as small as we want). A the function that is $1$ everywhere but zero a any point of the form $x=1/n$ is a counter example for (iii).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning for ii) is correct.

For a counterexample to both i) and iii), define $f=0$ at the points $1,1/2,1/3,\dots$ Define $f=1$ elsewhere else. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,2]^*,$ $f\ge 0$ everywhere, and $f(1)=0$ is the minimum value of $f.$

Since the values of $f$ at $1,1/2,\dots$ do not affect the integral of $f,$ we have

$$F(x)=\int_1^x f(t)\,dt = \int_1^x 1\,dt =(x-1),\,x\in [0,2].$$

It follows that $F'(x)=1$ everywhere in $[0,2].$ But $f=0$ at the points $1,1/2,1/3, \dots$ Thus $F'(x)\ne f(x)$ for $x=1,1/2,1/3, \dots$ It follows that i) and iii) both fail for this $f.$

---

Proof of *: Let $\epsilon>0.$ We know $f$ is RI on $[\frac{\epsilon}{2},1].$ Thus there is a partition $P$ of $[\epsilon/2,1]$ such that $U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ Let $Q=\{0\}\cup P.$ Then $Q$ is a partition of $[0,1]$ and

$$U(Q,f)-L(Q,f)= (1-0)\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2}+ U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$$

It follows that $f$ is RI on $[0,1].$

Comment: I edited my original answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I've understand it better. However, why can we assure that the function is integrable? I've studied that if there is a finite amount of point-discontinuities the integrability holds, however in your function definiton there is an infinite amount. For (i) it would be enough to using the example applied to a single point (x=1) but can you give me a further reasoning on (iii) ?

Comment: Here is a nice exercise: Suppose $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is RI on $[c,b]$ for all $c,a<c<b.$ Then $f$ is RI on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b f =\lim_{c\to a^+}\int_c^bf$ Have you seen this?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it but I didn't thought of it. Then it would be enough to see that the supremum of the $x \in [a,b]$ for which f is integrable is exactly $x=b$ and then we can conclude than the function is integrable in $[a,b]$?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing there. Sketch: The idea is to choose $c$ close to $a.$ Find a partition $P$ of $[c,b]$ such that $U(f,P)-L(P,f)$ is small. Now let $Q=P\cup \{a\}.$ Because $c$ is close to $a,$ $U(f,Q)-L(Q,f)$ will be small. This gives $f$ RI on $[a,b].$

Comment: I added a short proof that $f$ is RI on $[0,1]$ in my answer.